# Running c# Process with higher privileges and password in Linux

Tags: c#, .net, linux, process

I'm trying to run a c# (.net6) process with higher privileges in Linux with a password that has a dollar sign ($) and it always fails.
I've tried:

```
var stInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    FileName = "echo",
    Arguments = " 'pas$word' | sudo -S ping 127.0.0.1"
    UseShellExecute = false,
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    RedirectStandardError = true,
    CreateNoWindow = true,
};
```

But I receive everything as part of echo, and the stdout is:

```
'pas$word' | sudo -S ping 127.0.0.1
```

Then I tried calling bash with the arguments in a similar way as it works for me running from terminal `/bin/bash -c "echo 'pas\$word' | sudo -S ping 127.0.0.1"`:

```
var stInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    FileName = "/bin/bash",
    Arguments = "-c \"echo 'pas\$word' | sudo -S ping 127.0.0.1\""
    UseShellExecute = false,
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    RedirectStandardError = true,
    CreateNoWindow = true,
};
```

But that doesn't work and reports this over stderr:

```
[sudo] password for user: Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for user: 
sudo: no password was provided
sudo: 1 incorrect password attempt
```

I've tried different Arguments like:

```
Arguments = "-c \"echo pas$word | sudo -S ping 127.0.0.1\""
Arguments = "-c \"echo 'pas$word' | sudo -S ping 127.0.0.1\""
Arguments = "-c \"echo pas\\$word | sudo -S ping 127.0.0.1\""
Arguments = "-c \"echo 'pas\\$word' | sudo -S ping 127.0.0.1\""
Arguments = "-c \"echo pas\\\\$word | sudo -S ping 127.0.0.1\""
Arguments = "-c \"echo 'pas\\\\$word' | sudo -S ping 127.0.0.1\""
```

all of them with the same result.
I've tried as well using the `ArgumentList` instead of the `Arguments`, but same result.

Any idea to get it working?

**UPDATE**:
I've changed the password to one without dollar sign to avoid scaping it, and I continue having the same problem, so the problem is not scaping the dollar sign, but injecting the pwd to the process

Comment: Please try my solution with a password that doesn't have $ and if everything is fine, try it with $ and tell me the result. I hope it was useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this:

```cs
using System.Diagnostics;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var password    = ""; // Replace with your actual password
        var command     = "/bin/bash";
        var sudoCommand = "ping 127.0.0.1";
        var arguments   = $"-c \"echo '{password}' | sudo -S -p '' {sudoCommand}\"";

        ExecuteCommand(command, arguments);
    }

    static void ExecuteCommand(string command, string arguments)
    {
        var process = new Process
        {
            StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName               = command,
                Arguments              = arguments,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                RedirectStandardError  = true,
                UseShellExecute        = false,
                CreateNoWindow         = true
            }
        };

        process.Start();

        // Read the output and error streams
        var output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        var error  = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();

        process.WaitForExit();

        // Display the output and error
        Console.WriteLine("Output:");
        Console.WriteLine(output);

        Console.WriteLine("Error:");
        Console.WriteLine(error);
    }
}
```

I tested this on Ubuntu 22 and everything was fine.

Comment: It doesn't work for me in Ubuntu 22.04.03 with .net6:
`
Sorry, try again.
Output:

Error:

sudo: no password was provided
sudo: 1 incorrect password attempt
`
the password doesn't have any dollar sign. which c# version are you using?

Comment: @togarha **.NET 7**

Comment: @togarha I see this error when either I did not enter the password or the entered password is **wrong**.
Please make sure you entered the `password` variable correctly.

Comment: I tested in other 3 computers and it works fine, I don't know why the first computer where I tested still doesn't work, but seems related to just one computer, so we can say it's a good solution